# Regular Expression for Pseudocode - Trim Spacing

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex here: `\[link=["](?<href>[^"]+)["]\](?<title>[^\[]+)\[/link\]` and a replace string here: `<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"_blank\">${title}</a>`

It takes this string `[link="http://www.cnn.com"]CNN Webpage[/link]` and converts it to this: `<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">CNN Webpage</a>`

I need to amend it to take into account any leading/trailing spaces in either capture group, and trim them out in the replace string. 
ex: `[link="http://www.cnn.com "] CNN Webpage[/link]` to `<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">CNN Webpage</a>`

Regex is not my strong suit. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do it by adding `\s*` and turning the greedy `[^"]+` to lazy `[^"]+?`:

```
\[link="\s*(?<href>[^"]+?)\s*"\]\s*(?<title>[^[]+?)\s*\[/link\]
         ^              ^  ^     ^               ^  ^
```

See [demo on regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5blink%3d%22%5cs*(%3f%3chref%3e%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%3f)%5cs*%22%5c%5d(%3f%3ctitle%3e%5b%5e%5b%5d%2b)%5c%5b%2flink%5c%5d&i=%5blink%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.cnn.com+%22%5d+CNN+Webpage%5b%2flink%5d%0d%0a%5blink%3d%22+http%3a%2f%2fwww.cnn.com%22%5d+CNN+Webpage%5b%2flink%5d&r=%3ca+href%3d%22%24%7bhref%7d%22+target%3d%22_blank%22%3e%24%7btitle%7d%3c%2fa%3e)

Code:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"\[link=""\s*(?<href>[^""]+?)\s*""\]\s*(?<title>[^[]+?)\s*\[/link\]");
var str = "[link=\"http://www.cnn.com \"] CNN Webpage[/link]\n[link=\" http://www.cnn.com\"] CNN Webpage[/link]";
var output = rgx.Replace(str, "<a href=\"${href}\" target=\"_blank\">${title}</a>");
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly answered, and helpful explanation. Thank you!